# Counting rows in a sheet which match conditions across columns

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Let's say I've got an Excel sheet, the first few rows of which looks like this:

[image: bank-data portion of sheet]

In another sheet in this notebook, I want to count the number of instances where *pep* is *YES* or *NO*. This is easily done using the *COUNTIF* function with the **pep** variable referring to the data in the column with the header *pep*:

[image: bank-data working sheet]

However, now I want to count the number of rows which match certain conditions involving 2 or more different columns. For example, I want to count the number of rows where the *children* attribute is 0, and where the *pep* attribute is *YES*. **Is this possible using the *COUNTIF* function? If not, is there a simple way to do this?**

I'm using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the “Countifs” function.

Use the example formula below:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"=0",B:B,"=YES")
```

[image]